# How can I copy files bigger than 5 GB in Amazon S3?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto

Amazon S3 REST API documentation says there's a size limit of 5gb for upload in a PUT operation. Files bigger than that have to be uploaded using multipart. Fine.

However, what I need in essence is to rename files that might be bigger than that. As far as I know there's no rename or move operation, therefore I have to copy the file to the new location and delete the old one. How exactly that is done with files bigger than 5gb? I have to do a multipart upload from the bucket to itself? In that case, how splitting the file in parts work?

From reading boto's source it doesn't seem like it does anything like this automatically for files bigger than 5gb. Is there any built-in support that I missed?

Comment: Note that using the standard [resource copy](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.copy) -- ```s3.meta.client.copy(copy_source, 'otherbucket', 'otherkey')``` now **automatically uses a multipart upload** if the file is greater than 5GB

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> As far as I know there's no rename or move operation, therefore I have
>   to copy the file to the new location and delete the old one.

That's correct, it's pretty easy to do for objects/files smaller than 5 GB by means of a [PUT Object - Copy](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectCOPY.html) operation, followed by a [DELETE Object](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectDELETE.html) operation (both of which are supported in [boto](https://github.com/boto/boto) of course, see [copy_key()](http://docs.pythonboto.org/en/latest/ref/s3.html#boto.s3.bucket.Bucket.copy_key) and [delete_key()](http://docs.pythonboto.org/en/latest/ref/s3.html#boto.s3.bucket.Bucket.delete_key)):

> This implementation of the PUT operation creates a copy of an object
>   that is already stored in Amazon S3. A PUT copy operation is the same
>   as performing a GET and then a PUT. Adding the request header,
>   x-amz-copy-source, makes the PUT operation copy the source object into
>   the destination bucket.

However, that's indeed not possible for objects/files greater than 5 GB:

> **Note**
>   [...] You create a copy of your object up to 5 GB in size in a single atomic
>   operation using this API. **However, for copying an object greater than
>   5 GB, you must use the multipart upload API**. For conceptual
>   information [...], go to [Uploading Objects Using Multipart Upload](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/uploadobjusingmpu.html) [...] *[emphasis mine]*

Boto meanwhile supports this as well by means of the [copy_part_from_key()](http://docs.pythonboto.org/en/latest/ref/s3.html#boto.s3.multipart.MultiPartUpload.copy_part_from_key) method; unfortunately the required approach isn't documented outside of the respective [pull request #425 (allow for multi-part copy commands)](https://github.com/boto/boto/pull/425) (I haven't tried this myself yet though):

```py
import boto
s3 = boto.connect_s3('access', 'secret')
b = s3.get_bucket('destination_bucket')
mp = b.initiate_multipart_upload('tmp/large-copy-test.mp4')
mp.copy_part_from_key('source_bucket', 'path/to/source/key', 1, 0, 999999999)
mp.copy_part_from_key('source_bucket', 'path/to/source/key', 2, 1000000000, 1999999999)
mp.copy_part_from_key('source_bucket', 'path/to/source/key', 3, 2000000000, 2999999999)
mp.copy_part_from_key('source_bucket', 'path/to/source/key', 4, 3000000000, 3999999999)
mp.copy_part_from_key('source_bucket', 'path/to/source/key', 5, 4000000000, 4999999999)
mp.copy_part_from_key('source_bucket', 'path/to/source/key', 6, 5000000000, 5500345712)
mp.complete_upload()
```

You might want to study the respective samples on how to achieve this in Java or .NET eventually, which might provide more insight into the general approach, see  [Copying Objects Using the Multipart Upload API](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/CopyingObjctsMPUapi.html).

Good luck!

---

#### Appendix

Please be aware of the following peculiarity regarding copying in general, which is easily overlooked:

> When copying an object, you can preserve most of the metadata
>   (default) or specify new metadata. **However, the ACL is not preserved
>   and is set to private for the user making the request**. To override the
>   default ACL setting, use the x-amz-acl header to specify a new ACL
>   when generating a copy request. For more information, see Amazon S3
>   ACLs. *[emphasis mine]*

Comment: Good answer and thanks for pointing out that this is not documented. I have created an issue to track this: https://github.com/boto/boto/issues/729

Comment: This is now documented! http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/s3.html#module-boto.s3.multipart

And should probably note that the last byte in the last chunk should be the file size - 1, to head off any off-by-one errors.

Comment: Old post, I know, but AWS/boto3 now supports a simple copy (S3.Client.copy) with built-in multipart when necessary. See http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.copy
Thanks for your original reply here!

Answer (score 10):

The above was very close to working, unfortunately should have ended with `mp.complete_upload()`
instead of the typo `upload_complete()`!

I've added a working boto s3 multipart copy script here, based of the AWS Java example and tested with files over 5 GiB:

https://gist.github.com/joshuadfranklin/5130355

Answer (score 3):

The now standard `.copy` method will perform multipart uploads for files larger than 5gb. [Official Docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.copy)

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
copy_source = {
    'Bucket': 'mybucket',
    'Key': 'mykey'
}
s3.meta.client.copy(copy_source, 'otherbucket', 'otherkey')
```

Comment: How to preserve metadata?

Comment: @MattKucia I don't believe this is supported, see https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/1145

Comment: hook = S3Hook(aws_conn_id="awesome-conn-id", region_name="us-east-1", ...)
    s3_client = hook.conn
    s3_client.copy(...)

Comment: https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/28743

Answer (score 2):

I found this method to upload files bigger than 5gigs and modified it to work with a Boto copy procedure. 
here's the original: http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/s3_tut.html

```
import math
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection
from boto.exception import S3ResponseError


conn = S3Connection(host=[your_host], aws_access_key_id=[your_access_key],
                    aws_secret_access_key=[your_secret_access_key])

from_bucket = conn.get_bucket('your_from_bucket_name')
key = from_bucket.lookup('my_key_name')
dest_bucket = conn.get_bucket('your_to_bucket_name')

total_bytes = key.size
bytes_per_chunk = 500000000

chunks_count = int(math.ceil(total_bytes/float(bytes_per_chunk)))
file_upload = dest_bucket.initiate_multipart_upload(key.name)
for i in range(chunks_count):
    offset = i * bytes_per_chunk
    remaining_bytes = total_bytes - offset
    print(str(remaining_bytes))
    next_byte_chunk = min([bytes_per_chunk, remaining_bytes])
    part_number = i + 1
    file_upload.copy_part_from_key(dest_bucket.name, key.name, part_number,
                                   offset, offset + next_byte_chunk - 1)
file_upload.complete_upload()
```

Comment: Versions prior to boto3 really sucks at handling multipart upload. From version 3 on this is easier. Thanks for the sample, saved my day.