# using boto to upload csv file into Amazon S3 bucket

Tags: python-2.7, csv, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

I am trying to upload csv file to my existing Amazon S3 bucket named 'my-bucketname' in python using boto

I get an error 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'set_contents_from_filename'

So i guess I am not able to establish connection properly with S3 bucket.

Could anyone help me with this?

Here is my code.

```
s3conn = boto.connect_s3(aws_access_key_id,aws_secret_access_key)
upload_file = '/home/csvfilename.csv'
key = s3conn.get_bucket('my-bucketname').get_key('csvfilename.csv')
key.set_contents_from_filename(upload_file)
```

**UPDATED**

```
    s3Conn = boto.connect_s3(access_key,secret_key)
    bucket2 = self.s3Conn.lookup('my-bucket-name')
    k = Key(bucket2)
    k.Key = "sg_details.csv"
    k.set_contents_from_filename("sg_details.csv")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bucket2 = conn.lookup(bucketname)
k = Key(bucket2) 
k.key = filename
  k.set_contents_from_filename(filename) 
print('Completed')
```

Try this, this should work properly. I am not sure why you used getkey

Comment: Ok. That uploads file but the filename is some random characters and not my actual filename. In my code "uploadfile" contains the entire path of my file and "key" contains just the file name. set_contents_from_filename contains "uploadfile" in argument

Comment: Did you set k.key = filename? Whatever you set k.key that will be your file name

Comment: Yes. I did set k.key to my filename. I was searching a bit on internet and I guess I need to add headers to make sure filename remains same. Though not sure.

Comment: I don't think so. I just used the filename I had and it worked well. Does your filename consists of any special characters?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28116881/amazon-s3-upload-fails-using-boto-python check this out. That's my code in question and it works perfectly. Check if you got any thing wrong in your code.

Comment: Do not see anything much different in your code. Seems ok. Not sure why the name is still not appearing as expected. I tried removing '_' and '.csv' from filename. Still it uploaded as some 32 characters random filename

Comment: It places a randow characters as filename when we don't pass filename to it.

Comment: Oh that's strange, I've always used key and it worked for me. I've uploaded hundreds of files using that method. However I'm glad this worked for you.